# Constructing a set by picking the first element in each set in a family of sets. How to do that?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set of sets, say, disjoint sets of children born from the same parents.

F = { C1, C1, C3, C4 }.

Which set theoretic construction would allow to obtain the set :

{ x | x is the oldest child of his/her family } ?

Which functions / operations/ relations would be needed?

My reflection does not go further than this:

(1) creating an age order inside each set of children using functions from ench C-set to N ( attributing the number 1 to each oldest childs)

(2) taking the union of all ordering functions

(3) partitioning this union to obtain a cell with all pairs having 1 as second element

(4) in that cell of pairs, picking all first elements ( but how to do that?)

I'm asking for technical advices from trained mathematicians to improve this attempt at constructing the set I want.

Comment: What sort of formality are you looking to work in? For most purposes, the original way you write it will be fine.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft.  This is a somewhat gratuitous question. I'm interested in semantics and I first asked myself how to construct set theoretically / extensionnally some complex natural language predicates such as " monday" ( set of first days in each week). The question I am asking here is nearly the same.

Comment: If it is about semantics, then I fail to see how it is a mathematical question at all.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft . The purpose is related to semantics. But I thought  that there might be  some mathematical techniques available to construct such a set. That's why I ask for an advice from trained mathematicians. Are there situations in mathematics where such a " picking function" ( considered abstractly) would be of some use?

Comment: But it is not clear to me why the first formulation is not fine for your purposes, seeing as those purposes have not been stated explicitly.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft. I'm not satisfied with this formulation. I think I have a problem at step (4) to extract all  first elements  of the ordered pairs that are in the partition cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a finite totally ordered set. Formally, this is really a *pair*, $(P,\leq)$, there $P$ is a set, and $\leq$ is a binary relation on $P$, $\leq\subseteq P\times P$, which satisfies the following conditions:
1. For all $x\in P$, $(x,x)\in \leq$.
2. For all $x,y\in P$, if $(x,y)\in\leq$ and $(y,x)\in\leq$, then $x=y$.
3. For all $x,y,z\in P$, if $(x,y)\in\leq$ and $(y,z)\in\leq$, then $(x,z)\in\leq$.
4. For all $x,y\in P$, either $(x,y)\in\leq$ or $(y,x)\in\leq$.

(We usually write "$x\leq y$" instead of $(x,y)\in\leq$, but formally we are saying that a certain element is in the set.)

Given that ordered set, you can define the set $m=\{x\in P\mid \forall y(y\in P\rightarrow x\leq y)\}$. This set will contain exactly one element, the minimum of $m$ (if $(P,\leq)$ has no minimum then $m=\varnothing$). That $M$ is a set follows from the Axiom of Separation.

Likewise you can define the set you want as $M=\{x\in P\mid \forall y(y\in P\rightarrow y\leq x)\}$.

Comment: @Arthuro Magidin. Thanks a lot.  Do I understand correctly if I say that M is the set of maximal elements of P = C1 u C2  u C3 u C4 ordered by " x is younger than y"?

Comment: @ArthuroMagidin. But certainly my understanding must not be corrrect. Since the ordering you defined is total, the set of maximal elements must be a singleton.... I'll look at this more carefully to understand better. There must be something I am missing.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames: Wait: you said $P=\{C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4\}$; that is **different** from $C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3\cup C_4$. The former has exactly four elements: they are $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, and $C_4$. The latter has as elements whatever elements are **inside** $C_1$ and *inside* $C_2$, and *inside* $C_3$, and *inside* $C_4$.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames: No, the way I defined $M$, it either consists of a **single** element which is the maximum of $P$ under the ordering $\leq$, or else, if no maximum exists, then $M$ is empty. If $P$ has maximal-but-not-maximum elements, then $M$ is empty as defined.

Comment: @ArthuroMagidin. You're right I said P = {C1,C2,C3,C4}. I was simply wondering on which set the ordering was defined, and I asked myself whether it was defined on P or on the union of its elements. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames: If you are putting an order among the elements of $P$, you say that this is an order **on $\mathbf{P}$**. That's the nomenclature.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames: There is an autocomplete when you ping. No need to keep misspelling my name; that takes more work than not doing it.

Comment: @ArthuroMagidin. My misunderstanding comes from the fact that I first used ( in the body of the question) the name " F " for my family of sets {C1,C2,C3,C4}. So I thought the name "P" could possibly denote another set. But that is clear to me now.